# How to use NonNullByDefault on a package

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-warnings

My compiler warns me about `A default nullness annotation has not been specified for the package`. I'm using Juno with Java 7.

The documentation stats you should add `@NonNullByDefault` as a package option, but I don't know what that means.

Can I somehow set `NonNullByDefault` for the whole package? In Eclipse I can't right click on a package and say `add option` or something similar.

Or do I just add `@NonNullByDefault` to any class in a package and then it's valid for all beans in that package? Or do I have to create some meta info file in the pakage to add package options? I must be blind because I can't find any help online....

A small example would be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Summary:**
Getting the above advice to work was not intuitive to me. Nor was the actual solution I just figured out. In the package-info.java file:
 a. **put the annotation ABOVE the package declaration**
 b. **put the NonNullByDefault annotation import AFTER the package declaration**

---

**Details:**
I don't know if I am the only person who read the above answers and couldn't figure out how to get this working. So, just to be extra clear, here's the (non-obvious nor intuitive) steps I took to get this to finally work in Eclipse-Juno:

1. In Package Explorer, goto the root Java package showing the warning (or error) message starting with "**A default nullness annotation has not been specified for the package...**" - for this example, please assume the package name of "org.public_domain"
2. On the Java package, activate the right-click-menu and select the "**New -> Package**" option - yes, I know your package already exists, consider it an eclipse idiosyncrasy - it's not going to do anything to your existing package
3. When the "**New Java Package**" dialog appears, check the "**Create package-info.java**" checkbox and click "Finish"
4. Your Java editor will now have a new file titled "**package-info.java**" displayed with the following content:

   ```
   /**
    * 
    */
   /**
    * @author xyz
    *
    */  
   package org.public_domain;
   ```
5. Now, rearrange the file content to look like this:

   ```
   /**
    * 
    */
   /**
    * @author xyz
    *
    */  
   @NonNullByDefault  
   package org.public_domain;  
   import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
   ```

   ...or like this...

   ```
   /**
    * 
    */
   /**
    * @author xyz
    *
    */  
   @org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
   package org.public_domain;
   ```
6. Enjoy the awesomeness that is eclipse @NonNullByDefault

My challenge was figuring out that I was to **put the annotation ABOVE the package declaration**. And to **put the NonNullByDefault annotation import AFTER the package declaration**. For me, that was not intuitive.

Hope this saves someone else the time I've ended burning up chasing down this particular pathway.

Comment: I had quite some effort figuring out how to apply the info from the very short answer :-) Nice work summarizing it more understandably., this is golden.

Comment: It may look less confusing if you put a qualified `@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault` before the *package* declaration, no need to import just for this single use :)

Comment: And where is this org.eclipse.jdt.an...... class located?  If you create a simple Java project that library is not added.  I'm using Eclipse Mars.   Never mind, I see now that there is a auto-correct wizard to add the library.

Comment: Lots of googling and I finally managed to get it working with this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Josef.B you can find the answer here: http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_annotations.htm&cp=1_3_9_0

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to get rid of the warning and ignore this feature because you're not making use of it, you can simply disable it in the Eclipse preferences:

**Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Null analysis > Missing '@NonNullByDefault' annotation on package *= [Ignore]***

Answer (score 3):

See the [source code](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/tools/org.eclipse.objectteams/trunk/contrib/jdt-null-annotations/src/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.java) or JavaDocs:

```
Note that for applying an annotation to a package a file by the name
package-info.java is used.
```

And:

```
@Target({PACKAGE,TYPE,METHOD,CONSTRUCTOR})
```

Comment: bingo :-) I though package-info is a JAXB specific thingy, but now I'm wiser

Comment: Is there an easy way to add package-info.java from Eclipse?  It seems really strange that there is no "Quick Fix" for this error, and eclipse refuses to make a package-info.java java class the "normal" way.

Comment: @BillK I also struggled with that and found that probably the easiest workaround is to create a new package using Eclipse's wizard. It has a checkbox for "Create package-info.java". Once generated, you can add the `@NonNullByDefault` annotation to it then copy it to any other package. When I do it in the Package Explorer window, Eclipse automatically updates package name in the copied file :)

Comment: @szeryf You can actually create an existing package "again" using that dialog just to add the package-info.java. I.e. ticking that box allows you to click finish if there's no existing package-info