# Compilation error: Default nullness annotation has not been specified

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable

Platform: Windows

Eclipse Version: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.3M7-201305020800/

Test Case:

```
public class Test {

}
```

Error: A default nullness annotation has not been specified for the type Test

I have null analysis enabled.

Could you please let me know what the error message means and how to fix it.

Thanks,

Gudge.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. It is somewhat related to 
[How to use NonNullByDefault on a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623805/how-to-use-nonnullbydefault-on-a-package/16410330#16410330).

One creates a package-info.java file and puts the following:
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault(true).

Hope it helps people in future.

Thanks